# Deploy Azure Funtions with Environment variables - Nodejs

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have a Azure Function Nodejs implementation in local, where I can use environment variable in `local.settings.json` file.

Once I deploy, I can't find these variables in the portal which causes error,

Should I manually include these settings in `Configuration -> Application settings` in portal or any other better way.

Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To publish the code along with the app settings as one unit, you can use the following command from the CLI:

```
func azure functionapp publish <YourFunctionAppName> --publish-local-settings -i --overwrite-settings -y
```

then you can see that local variables have been copied across with the right values.

Comment: Is there is a way to do without az cli, like directly through visual studio code ?

Comment: you can do via portal or cli, or have it in your code https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node#environment-variables